# Eclipse with EGit, git-blame info is hard to see

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit, blame

using Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2, with EGit plugin and JDK 1.7. I've seen that it should support blame annotations, but I can't get it to show like I see [here on Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/1.0.0#Blame_Annotations).

Here's how it looks for me, you can't see the pointer but I'm hovering over the vertical brown line:

[image]

Anyone know how to expand the annotations view?

Comment: To see that vertical brown line appear in Eclipse Juno, we need to first right-click on the file and select `Team -> Show Annotations`

Comment: Hint: enable line numbers and the vertical ruler will be much wider allowing you to hover the ruler easier.

Comment: In Eclipse Kepler, you have to do `Team -> Show Annotations`. Then, in the history right click on the first commit and select `Show Annotations`.

Comment: Since Neon (I believe) `Show Annotations` has been renamed to `Show Revision Information`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Right-click on the brown line, *Revisions -> Show Author*.

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense. Unfortunately, with most(/some?) Eclipse plugins, the correct menu selection is `Team – Show Annotations` to enable them  and `Revisions - Hide Revision Information` to disable them. That's right, the enabling and disabling must be done via different submenu!

Comment: If you right click on the left line (the one you use to set breakpoints) you can click "Show Annotations" from that menu. To turn then off, in the same menu, there's also "Revisions -> Hide Revision Information". The latter only appears after you've clicked "Show Annotations".